# Cast a new column and then cross compare to another table in where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I am currently working with sql server management studio. I have 2 tables. The first table has 2 columns, col1 is a smalldatetime, and col2 is also a smalldatetime. The second table has 3 columns, a varchar(25) column, a bit column, and a smalldatetime column.

My question is this: With table 1, I am creating the varchar string in the second table with the smalldatetime. I need a way to cross compare the smalldatetime created number, to the varchar in table 2. My code is below:

```
SELECT Distinct
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) AS 'CreatedNumber', table1.col2
FROM table1 WHERE table1.col2 IS NULL 
AND [CreatedNumber] NOT IN (SELECT table2.col1 FROM table2)
```

My error is occuring on the last line where you see "[CreatedNumber]." The problem is that this is not a column name so I can not use my creatednumber column to do any kind of function in the where clause. Do I need to use a cast function or create a table to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbl.CreatedNumber,
    tbl.col2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
        + RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
        + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) 
        + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, table1.col1) AS varchar), 2) AS 'CreatedNumber', 
        table1.col2
    FROM 
        table1 
) AS tbl
WHERE 
    tbl.col2 IS NULL 
    AND tbl.[CreatedNumber] NOT IN (SELECT table2.col1 FROM table2)
```

Comment: This appears to be working but I want to make sure I understand what it is doing. Are you creating a table with the first 13 lines and then naming it tbl?

Comment: @Cheddar : I'm using a sub query for getting the data. The reason is that you can't use a alias colum directly in the where statement. With a sub query on your original select. We can reach the concated column and use it in the where statement. For more information look at sub queries